# Irreducible set of a Functional Dependency

Tags: functional-dependencies

I currently have the Set/Functional Dependencies:

Relation R{A, B, C, D, E, F } satisfies the following FDs:

```
AB → C C→A BC → D ACD → B BE → C CE → FA CF → BD D →EF
```

I have the answer:

```
{A B → C, C → A, B C → D, B E → C, C E → F, C F → B D, D → E F}
```

However I know that irreducible sets cannot have two attributes on the right hand side.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As we know we should follow 3 properties that satisfies.
One of them is: RHS (Dependent) attributes be in singleton form.
If it violates it will led to Non-Irreducible set.

Answer (score 0):

first decompose the FD that having more than one attribute on the LHS.

i.e. CE->FA

then take CE->F and CE->A

and CF → BD

then take CF->B and CF->D

now solve it,u get the answer.